# swift - how to save switch, even I change TableViews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

```
import UIkit
// ViewController file
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UIViewController{

    @IBAction func aaaSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if (sender.isOn == true)
        {
            ClickCounterA+=2
            UserDefaults.standard.set(aaaSwitch, forKey: "aaaSwitch")
            UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "aaaSwitch")
            defaults.set(aaaSwitch, forKey: "aaaSwitch")
        }
        else
        {
            defaults.set(aaaSwitch, forKey: "aaaSwitch")
        }
    }
```

I change the switch(aaaSwitch) in tableview and move to another tableview. After that, I return to the first tableview, the switch is the statement before I change. In other words, I can't save the switch statement.

Comment: When I turn off the switch, even I move to the tableciew and return from checking conter to looking the switch, the switch is still off.  I want that if switch is false, a counter which is in another table view is subtracted two.

Comment: Save the state in `model`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're passing aaaSwitch, the method, into the UserDefaults set calls.  You want to be passing in a value, in this case a boolean value.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "aaaSwitch")
```

If you really wanted to archive your entire UISwitch, you'd need to first convert it to an NSData (and you'd likely have to come up with an algorithm for doing so). And I can see no point in ever wanting to do that.  Surely you just want to persist its on/off state, so use the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UIViewController{
        @IBOutlet weak var aaaswitch: UISwitch!
        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                aaaswitch.isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "aaaSwitch")
        }
        @IBAction func aaaSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
            if (sender.isOn == true)
                {
                        ....
                }
                else
                {
                        ....
                }
                UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "aaaSwitch")
        }
 }
```

Comment: I also want to know how to connect the label in TableView with ViewController.

Comment: Explain briefly

Comment: Labels in table View cells can’t connect to ViewController with using control key.

Comment: Did you got the answer?

Comment: No, I didn’t. I know labels in tableviewcontroller can’t connect to ViewController so I’m trying to connect labels in ViewController (not table), but I get SIGABRT error.

Comment: Accept this answer and post your question in new one, if you got how to save switch.